# Can't locate Class/MethodMaker.pm in @INC

Tags: oracle, ssh, putty

I am trying to create iLDT file in order to upload to oracle server on putty. But when I try to run command to create that, I have encountered the message below :

```
  Can't locate Class/MethodMaker.pm in @INC (@INC contains:/media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/apps_st/appl/fnd/12.0.0/perl /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/apps_st/appl/fnd/12.0.0/xml/orc115 /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/apps_st/appl/fnd/12.0.0/perl/FND/irep/repo /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/apps_st/appl/fnd/12.0.0/bin/ /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/tech_st/10.1.3/perl/lib/5.8.3/i686-linux-thread-multi /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/tech_st/10.1.3/perl/lib/5.8.3 /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/tech_st/10.1.3/perl/lib/site_perl/5.8.3/i686-linux-thread-multi /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/tech_st/10.1.3/perl/lib/site_perl/5.8.3 /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/apps_st/appl/au/12.0.0/perl /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/tech_st/10.1.3/Apache/Apache/mod_perl/lib/site_perl/5.8.3/i686-linux-thread-multi /ade/smayer_perl58_main_linux/perl58/bin/Linux/Opt/lib/5.8.3/i686-linux-thread-multi /ade/smayer_perl58_main_linux/perl58/bin/Linux/Opt/lib/5.8.3 /ade/smayer_perl58_main_linux/perl58/bin/Linux/Opt/lib/site_perl/5.8.3/i686-linux-thread-multi /ade/smayer_perl58_main_linux/perl58/bin/Linux/Opt/lib/site_perl/5.8.3 /ade/smayer_perl58_main_linux/perl58/bin/Linux/Opt/lib/site_perl .) at /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/apps_st/appl/fnd/12.0.0/perl/FND/irep/repo/Rep/Parser.pm line 24.

  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/apps_st/appl/fnd/12.0.0/perl/FND/irep/repo/Rep/Parser.pm line 24.

  Compilation failed in require at /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/apps_st/appl/fnd/12.0.0/bin/irep_parser.pl line 37.

  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /media/disk/oracle/VIS/apps/apps_st/appl/fnd/12.0.0/bin/irep_parser.pl line 37.
```

I am not accustomed to doing such things, so it may be a simple question. sorry about that

Comment: Hi Abdulbaki, Can you share how you resolved this issue?